# Python script runs fine for a while then returns MemoryError (python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pywin32

I have a small script which utilizes the Python Imaging Library module for Python3.3 (on Win7, 8 gb of RAM) to take a screenshot of a small (~40x50) pixel area of the screen once each second and compare it to an image which I already have to detect a particular pattern and execute two other modules I created if it is found. The script seems to work flawlessly for the first 30 minutes or so, but then the script crashes and I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug

  File "C:\Users\Nate Simon\Dropbox\CaptchaLibrary\detectNRun.py", line 68, in <module>:

    im2 = ImageGrab.grab((left,upper,right,lower))

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 47, in grab:

    size, data = grabber()

MemoryError`

I've adjusted the time between screenshots and all it does is delay when the program crashes.

Here is what seems to be the offending code:

```
im2 = ImageGrab.grab((left,upper,right,lower)) # Take a screenshot at given coordinates

for x in range(im2.size[0]): # This section just changes to image to black/white for better comparing but might be relevant.
    for y in range(im2.size[1]):
        pixel = im2.getpixel((x,y))
        if pixel[0] < 40 or pixel[1] < 40 or pixel[2] < 40:
            color = (0, 0, 0)
        else:
            color = (255, 255, 255)
        im2.putpixel((x,y), color)
```

There are no lists, dictionaries, or databases being added to in this script, every time it runs the old screenshot is overwritten in the memory (it is never saved to disk).

Also possibly relevant: from the time module I am using `sleep()` for delays and `time()` to keep track of system time. I am also using win32api for mouse/keyboard inputs and using tkinter to read the clipboard in the following lines:

```
    c = Tk()
    c.withdraw()
    result = c.clipboard_get()
    c.destroy()
```

In another section, the clipboard is cleared before new data is added with `c.clipboard_clear()`

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the issue with just the piece of code you give in order to make sure that it is what's causing it ? Just let it do screenshots like crazy until it crashes.

Comment: This is a crazy inefficient way to threshold an image.  Try using `Image.point` method instead of that nested loop, and see if your memory problems disappear.

Comment: I ran it again w/o delays and isolating parts of the code but I was unable to replicate the error. I guess I'll just work on isolating different parts until I find the issue. And @wim thanks for the tip, I'll implement that as soon as I can.

Comment: are you destroying the image object after manipulating it? Or are you just creating more and more images? If you create one new image every second, that will eat up a lot of memory after a while.

Comment: If you're using tkinter, you should never call `sleep`. Even though you've hidden the window, this really isn't the way Tkinter was designed to be used. By now allowing the app to service events, you may be preventing some garbage collecting. If you want to do something once a second, just use `after`.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find an adequate solution to completely solve the memory issue (or even replicate it under different conditions), so I simply increased the interval between actions from 1 second to 15 seconds and I have yet to get the memory error again.